# Xamarin transparent background image not showing as transparent (Grey and white)

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I am new to xamarin forms. I am trying to display an image with "Transparent background" (Grey and white) but this is how it show on the application. 
I am using PNG file for the picture as I saw the other thread commenting on PNG/JPG files but it did not work. 
I also try with opacity and backgroundcolor="Transparent" but it did not work either. 
The image is random transparent background image got from google.
Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

[Picture of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8tCM.png)

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="OrangeRed">
    <Image Source="icon11.png" Aspect="AspectFit" />
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: I guess if you open the image from computer, it displays the grey and white grids as well.  If so, make sure you download the "real transparent" png files.

Comment: @Shaw Thank you, Its mistake on my side for not checking the PNG files before asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Shaw mentioned in the comment, I made a blunder on the transparent background PNG files. 
I tested with a transparent background xamarin logo from pre-built xamarin form pages and it worked. 
Conclusion for my case: Double check if the picture actually has transparent background.

Detail Info:
The picture I used and shown above does not actually have transparent background, one can check when open it from your PC (It will shows the white and grey boxes). 
[Not "Real" Transparent Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHTxv.jpg) 
[Actual Transparent Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SflKc.png)

Comment: You can add more details to your post and then mark it as an answer. It's helpful to others facing the same problem. Thanks in advance!